# Can we interchange derivatives when multiplied?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, physics

Although this looks like a physics question, this is more of a Math question, 
I was reading the Energy-Mass relationship derivation, it goes as follows,

Force $F$ is given by

$$F=\frac{d}{dt}(mv)$$
$$=\frac{dm}{dt}v+m\frac{dv}{dt}$$

And kinetic energy $K$
$$dK=F \cdot ds$$
So, $$dK=\frac{dm}{dt}v\cdot ds+m\frac{dv}{dt} \cdot ds$$

The next step what I don't understand

$$dK=dm \cdot v \cdot \frac{ds}{dt}+m \cdot dv \cdot \frac{ds}{dt}$$

Can we really write something like for example $$\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt}dy \bigg) \space \text{as} \space \bigg (dx \frac{dy}{dt} \bigg)?$$
I dont think that is valid, or am I missing out something?

Should I continue reading it or throw away the book?

Comment: That does look like something physicists would do, yes.

Comment: you mean its not valid in the strict sense? can that still be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that from the chain rule, we can write

$$\frac{dx}{dt}dy=\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}dx=\frac{dy}{dt}dx$$

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  And please don't feel that way.  You'll be fine.  -Mark